# If matrix A is orthogonal, show that transpose of A is equal to the inverse of A

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonal-matrices

If matrix A is orthogonal (dot product of each pair of its columns is zero; also dot product of each pair of its rows is 0; dot product of each row or column with itself is 1), show that $A^T = A^{-1}$.

I'm stuck with this proof because I'm not sure how to theoretically calculate $A^TA$ and $AA^T$.

Comment: You will find this result in hundreds of lecture notes. It is even an equivalence. In some cases, this characteristic property is taken as a definition of orthogonal matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\langle,\rangle$ a scalar product on $R^n$, $A$ is orthogonal if and only if for every $x,y\in R^n$, $\langle x,y\rangle =\langle A(x),A(y)\rangle$. This is equivalent to saying that $\langle AA^T(x),y\rangle=\langle x,y\rangle$. This is equivalent to $AA^T=Id$.